# fusion tables - Calling the API from a browser using JavaScript - uncaught typeError

Tags: json, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to get some data out of a Google Fusion Table.

I have used the Google documentation to produce a JSON file using by calling the Fusion Tbales API like so: 
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%yyyyyy&key=xxxxxxxxx"

I now what to incorporate this call into a webpage and display the results on the same  page.

I have followed the instructions on this page which gives some example code (Calling the API from a browser using JavaScript):
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started#JS

I have put the code on my site and replaced the script call with the one from the top of this post.

When I view the page nothing displays on the page and i get an error in the Google console saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Does any one know of a better example or tutorial on this where the example code works?

OR

Does any on know why this script is failing?

The code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Fusion Tables API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
    function handler(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // Either show the body or the automatic columns of the template
        if (item.body) {
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.body;
        } else {
          for (var j = 0; j < item.automaticColumnNames.length; j++) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.automaticColumnNames[j];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
 <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20xxxxq5TFqB4oM-HCQBkRqzOM6uC2qAIJDk91Q&keyXXXXXXXX"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your code look like? What does your table look like? Do you have downloads enabled for your table?

Comment: All the code is on the link I gave. The only thing I have changed from that is the <script> link to the fusion tables API. That code is also in my post at the top. As I said that works if I use the API call directly in the browser navbar. So yes the table is published. I have id, name, and longlat columns in the table. But what I can see from the JavaScript the code determines the column on the fly. They're not predefined.

Comment: In StackOverflow, you should post the relevant in your post, not just links.  Without at least the table number there is not enough information in your post to help.  _You_ can run a debugger on your code and see what the problem is, we can't.

Comment: hi @geocodezip. Ive added the code from the page now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code, I get a javascript error in Chrome:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20XXXXXXX&key=XXXXXXX' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

You are missing the "callback=handler" parameter in your query (from the example you quote).

Once I fix that your parsing routine is not correct for the data returned, there is no items property of the response.  This works for me:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Fusion Tables API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
    function handler(response) {
      var contentStr = "<table>";
      for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
        var item = response.rows[i];
        contentStr += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
          contentStr += "<td>" + item[j]+"</td>";
        }
        contentStr += "</tr>";
      }
      contentStr += "</table>";
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = contentStr;
    }
    </script>
 <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20XXXXX=XXXXXX&callback=handler"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTablesAPIv1QueryB.html)

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip, I've had a look for documentation on achieving the same as this question, but in PHP instead of JavaScript. As I usually develop in PHP. I found little on this subject and a developer wiki that was lacking examples. Do you know if it would be possible? Or, do you have any better JavaScript examples that would make it easier to control the formatting of the output. I want more control over layout. You seem to be the expert in google maps around here!

Comment: I don't do PHP (at least not much).  Control the formatting of the output by the dynamically generated HTML (you can add css classes and style to that).

Comment: For any one who wants to know how to do this in PHP read this excellent article / example: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 It takes you threw the whole set up from setting up your table and to displaying the info on the page. The final part to get the pins on to the map is in JavaScript however.

Comment: Sorry, I could have pointed you to that. Thought you were looking for FusionTables code (Google has some libraries and documentation on that also if you look in the FusionTables docs).